# How can I get the changes when users click on my list of options using react-hook-forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

This is my app:

```
export const WithReactHookForm = () => {
  const optionsList = [
    {
      value: 'FIRST_VALUE_OF_OPTION',
      option: 'Uma opção',
    },
    {
      value: 'SECOND_VALUE__OF_OPTION',
      option: 'Outra opção',
    },
  ];

  const { handleSubmit, formState, register } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      reason: '',
    },
    mode: 'all',
  });

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
        <CustomSelectInput
          optionsList={optionsList}
          name="reason"
          ref={register({ required: 'This field is required' })}
        />
        <br />
        isValid: {`${formState.isValid}`}
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

This is my custom input component:

```
import React, { useState, forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import { SelectProps } from './models/Select';

import * as S from './styles';

const CustomSelectInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, SelectProps>(
  ({ name, optionsList, onChange }: SelectProps, ref) => {
    const [optSelected, setOptSelected] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const internalRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    useImperativeHandle<HTMLInputElement | null, HTMLInputElement | null>(ref, () => internalRef.current);

    const onOptionClicked = (position: number) => () => {
      setOptSelected(optionsList[position]?.option);

      // if (internalRef.current) {
      //   console.log('entrou', internalRef.current);

      //   internalRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
      // }
    };

    return (
      <>
        <input ref={internalRef} name={name} onChange={onChange} value={optSelected || ''} />

        <ul>
          {optionsList.map((option, i) => (
            <S.ListItem key={option + '-' + i} onClick={onOptionClicked(i)}>
              {option.option}
            </S.ListItem>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </>
    );
  },
);

export default CustomSelectInput;
```

My expectation is that when users click on the input element, a list of options will open (I know how to do it, but I removed it for the example). And when these users click on an item of this list, my react-hook-forms should be able to perceive this change, through the reference "internalRef" the same used by my input (this is my difficult).

I was trying to do it using the code inside onOptionClicked, where there is a commented code.

However, it only works when the user clicks for the second time on an item of the list.

[Animation with an example of behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY3QW.gif)